# How to create multiple sitemaps with php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create multiple sitemaps for my website using php mysql. Here is what I have tried but its not working. I have video titles in database and unique_ids. What I am trying to do is. First I store titles and unique ids in variables than. I replace spaces with (-) and than i put unique id at the end of titles. and from there I get all the titles in one unique varible $titleSEO. which is url of video but for some reason my code is not working.

```
require('db.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM pm_videos";
$result=mysql_query($query);

//whle loop
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $title=$row['video_title'];
            $unique=$row['unique_id'];
            $title2= strtolower(str_replace(array('  ', ' '), '-', preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 s]/', '', trim($title))));
            $titleSEO= "$title2-$unique";

$titleSEO = array_chunk($titleSEO, 50000);
$maxlinksinsitemap = 50000;
$numbersofsitemap = ceil($count_array / $maxlinksinsitemap);
$i = 1; 
if ($maxlinksinsitemap > 50000){
    $i=$i++;
}


    $cfile = 'sitemap_' . $i  . '.xml';
    $createfile = fopen($cfile, 'w');

    fwrite($createfile, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n");
    fwrite($createfile, "<urlset xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\"\n");
    fwrite($createfile, "xmlns:image=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1\"\n");
    fwrite($createfile, "xmlns:video=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1\">\n");


        $creat = "<url>\n";
        $creat .= "<loc>http://mimuz.com/" . $title . ".html</loc>\n";
        $creat .= "<priority>1.00</priority>\n";
        $creat .= "</url>\n";

        fwrite($createfile, $creat);

    fclose($createfile);




}
```

Comment: Can you expound upon "not working"?

Comment: Its not giving me any error and even no results its not generating any sitemap and I am not seeing any errors